# xamarin.forms - messaging center pass data to entry

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to display it on my entry which is not happening, if I use a View Model with messaging center it won't display, tell me what I'm doing wrong what should I have to do. I think the entry cant find the value in the messaging center.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Data1.Views.Page1">
      <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name = "lstView" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped" />
      </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstView.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" }; 
        }
        void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e == null) return; // has been set to null, do not 'process' tapped event
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Item);
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
            var person = new Person
            {
                Name = e.Item.ToString()
            };
            MessagingCenter.Send<Page1, string>(this, "Hi", e.Item.ToString());
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
        } 
    }

    public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page1, string>(this, "Hi", (sender, arg) => 
            {
                txttest.Text = arg;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're sending the message before Page2 has been created, so it doesn't exist yet to receive the message.  MessagingCenter does not queue messages for future delivery.  In this scenario it would be much simpler to just pass the value as a parameter to Page2's constructor.

Comment: Even if I use this and bind it to the entry still nothing:  public class MainViewModel
    {
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page1, string>(this, "Hi", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Person = new Person
                {
                    Name = arg
                };
            });
        }
       
    }

Comment: without seeing that code in context I can't tell if it addresses the issues I mentioned or not.

Answer (score -1):

pls

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Page1, string>(this, "Hi", e.Item.ToString());
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
```

change line and

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page2());
MessagingCenter.Send<Page1, string>(this, "Hi", e.Item.ToString());
```

maybe it's works try it